# add custom text next to chartvalues - achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm working on TimeSeries chart with temperature. I want to add a custom text next to the Chart values, for example we have 1,34 and 'hot' on the chart. Is it possible to add custom text to the chart values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently not possible.

However, you can add custom Y axis labels, if you need.

Support for annotations has been added to SVN. You can checkout the code according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout) page and run an `ant dist` in order to build an up to date achartengine.jar file including this fix.

Or you can use an intermediate version from [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/).

Comment: However, you can ask for such a feature here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list